# Sakumoto 3-pass MQ IDS Zero-Knowledge proof

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs

In this paper: [Public-Key Identification Schemes Based on Multivariate Quadratic Polynomials](https://www.iacr.org/archive/crypto2011/68410703/68410703.pdf)

it is explained in Theorem 2 that the 3-pass protocol is statistically zero knowledge when the commitment scheme Com is statistically hiding.

Then, there is a proof Proof sketch. The fact is that after that it is explained that:

> "The details of the proof are given **in the full paper**, where we
> formally construct a blackbox simulator S which has oracle access to a
> cheating verifier CV,and outputs a successful transcript with
> probability 2/3. Furthermore, the distribution of the output of S is
> shown to be statistically close to the distribution of the real
> transcript."

Does anybody know where this full paper is?

Comment: Did you consider asking the authors? It is also often the case that the authors have a "fuller" version but never took the time to finish entirely, hence never made it available online, but they will usually share it upon request.

Comment: I try to do it today

Comment: Another thing worth checking: if one of the authors was a master or phd student at the time of writing the paper, then their master/PhD thesis might contain a fully detailed proof.

Comment: Well it's look like no one of authors are a master or phd student